# Declined question flag

Tags: discussion, flagging, specific-flag

I flagged [A group whose automorphism group is cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160453/a-group-whose-automorphism-group-is-cyclic) for being off-topic, a standard procedure for questions that have no context/work. However, it was declined by a moderator. Why is that?

Comment: When did you flag that? You have 3.6k points, and after 3k you shouldn't be able to flag something into closing (e.g. as off topic), but rather vote to close it yourself.

Comment: @Asaf "Review completed Feb 22 at 21:47: "

Comment: @quid: Ah. Well, it's better to ask three months later than to not know the answer at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The flag was not declined by a moderator, three reviewers in [the close vote queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/359447) unanimously voted to leave the question open. If the reviewers unanimously vote to leave open, that declines a close-flag without moderator intervention.

Comment: So why did those reviewers vote to leave open?

Comment: @VladimirLenin this is hard to know, but presumably because the question is interesting and well-received and there is a school of thought that mathemaically above average  can compensate lack on other aspects (or because they are not subscribing to the entire context idea).